# How to control overflow of table cell in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a table and want the first columns to have a vertical scroll bar. This works in Chrome, IE9, Safari on iPad but not in Firefox? Why not? What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        <p>Test</p>
                        ...
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="col2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

table {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

table .col1 {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
}

table .col1>div.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto; 
}

table .col2 {
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: When do you need the scroll bars to appear?

Comment: There can be some 100 "Test"-lines and I only want this cell to have a scroll bar. With this code I get a scroll bar on the right side for the whole page (with Firefox, other browsers are ok).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue:

`overflow:scroll;` won't work inside a `table`.

If you do the same with a `div`, then it will work fine.

See [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WX8Jj/)

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col1" >
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
        <p>Test</p>
    ...
    </div>
</div><div class="col2">
</div>
```

More read: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2006Mar/0030.html#replies

Thanks to [kirtan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83664/kirtan)