# Two column layout: Problems with column

Tags: html, css

I created a simple two column layout based on this:
[How to control overflow of table cell in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547722/how-to-control-overflow-of-table-cell-in-firefox).

The left columns should be scrollable (top-down) and the right one should be fix.

HTML:

```
<div id="col1">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="row">Test 1</div>
        <div class="row">Test 2</div>
        <div class="row">Test 3</div>
        <div class="row">... more rows</div>
    </div>
</div><div id="col2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0c0;
}
#col1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #c00;
}
#col1>#list {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#col1>#list>.row {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#col2 {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #00c;
}
```

Please see this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bitas/qRtjN/

Firefox 18.0.2 shows it nearly as expected. In other browsers the left column doesn't start at the top of the page but in the lower left corner.

It works as expected if I remove the "div#list". What's wrong with this div? How I can I fix it?

Comment: Check this out:  Place the html <div id="col2"></div> on a new line and it changes everything!  Look at the jFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qRtjN/7/

Comment: I tried this already but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your CSS a bit and it does work. Here it is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0c0;
}
#col1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #c00;
}
#col1>#list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#col1>#list>.row {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#col2 {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #00c;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I changed the heights to 100% to match my needs. Thanks a lot.

There is a scroll bar even if there is next to no content in the left column. How can I remove this?

Comment: It didn't happen in my test. Can you show me the code where that happens ? Also if the answer helped you, please pick it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS will correct the alignment of your columns:

```
#col1, #col2 {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qRtjN/13/