# CSS overflow-x and white-space effect not working on Firefox (but working on Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a table with one column that has a long string of text.  I want this column to be a fixed small width, and have a horizontal scrollbar.  To achieve this, I'm using the following style for the long column:

```
.foo { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Here is a working example:
[jsfiddle.net/7Ld6c0vv](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ld6c0vv/)

In Chrome, all is well.  But in Firefox, there's no scrollbar, and the text in the column trails out beyond the column bounds.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 and Firefox 42.0.

How can this be modified so that the effect in Chrome also appears in Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control overflow of table cell in firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547722/how-to-control-overflow-of-table-cell-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ld6c0vv/2/ ?

Using a `<div class="foo">` contained inside the td:

```
<td><div class="foo">lhaoh oah ohgoa ngoa nhoganho gaoh goahg oaehgo eoghaogh aog aoghj aohg oehgo hegohao goah goeahgo aewhog haeoghaeo ghoae wgoiawhoeh ofhaioeh oag</div></td>
```